# When two equally opposite charges placed then which type of motion will carried out b/w them?

Tags: electrostatics

I want to know that which type of motion will carried out between two equally opposite charged particles, when they placed in front of each other.

Comment: neither. The correct (non-relativistic) description is through *orbitals*, which are the solutions of the Schrödinger equation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform that should have been an answer, if this weren't a duplicate

Comment: While this is now a very different question, I think it might be a bit broad, though it would certainly involve discussions on [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations), the [Lorentz force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) and numerical solutions thereof.

Comment: Leave everything for 1 minute  and just answer in terms of electrostatics please. I just wanna know what you thinks.

Comment: It would help if you would clarify the question. If you are not interested in the details of charged particles and electrodynamics, please change the question to ask about the motion of two particles experiencing just an inverse square law. Even then, this post may be found to go against the homework policy, so it would help if you can ask a specific conceptual question.